# Change name of the internet network service on CentOS

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, service

If I try `nmap` to my server (CentOS 7), I get something like this:

```
$ nmap myserver.com

Nmap scan report for myserver.com (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.93s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

I do not like the display service name. Can I set the name of the service on the server `myserver.com`??

**For example:**

I want get this line in output:

```
5432/tcp    open    myservice
```

instead of

```
5432/tcp    open    postgresql
```

Comment: Well, you can do what @lalokin suggests below and edit /etc/services, but why?  Do you understand the implications of doing this?  Are you aware it will only affect you, and that anyone else out there who scans your server will see it as the default?

Answer (score 2):

/etc/services maps port numbers to named services and is commonly used by local software to do port number lookups.

Please note, as stated in a comment above, that this will only change the name on the local machine. other machines will still use their local configuration.

I would also advice you not to change the service name as this might break other software trying to find the port for your pgsql service.